# python-twisted: writing a broadcaster

Tags: python, twisted

im learning python twisted and i refer to this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

"""
An example demonstrating how to send and receive UDP broadcast messages.

Every second, this application will send out a PING message with a unique ID.
It will respond to all PING messages with a PONG (including ones sent by
itself). You can tell how many copies of this script are running on the local
network by the number of "RECV PONG".

Run using twistd:

$ twistd -ny udpbroadcast.py
"""

from uuid import uuid4

from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.python import log



class PingPongProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    noisy = False

    def __init__(self, controller, port):
        self.port = port


    def startProtocol(self):
        self.transport.setBroadcastAllowed(True)


    def sendPing(self):
        pingMsg = "PING {0}".format(uuid4().hex)
        self.transport.write(pingMsg, ('<broadcast>', self.port))
        log.msg("SEND " + pingMsg)


    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        if datagram[:4] == "PING":
            uuid = datagram[5:]
            pongMsg = "PONG {0}".format(uuid)
            self.transport.write(pongMsg, ('<broadcast>', self.port))
            log.msg("RECV " + datagram)
        elif datagram[:4] == "PONG":
            log.msg("RECV " + datagram)



class Broadcaster(object):

    def ping(self, proto):
        proto.sendPing()


    def makeService(self):
        application = service.Application('Broadcaster')

        root = service.MultiService()
        root.setServiceParent(application)

        proto = PingPongProtocol(controller=self, port=8555)
        root.addService(internet.UDPServer(8555, proto))
        root.addService(internet.TimerService(1, self.ping, proto))

        return application


application = Broadcaster().makeService()
```

i noticed that for this broadcaster example, we need to run as `twistd -ny udpbroadcast.py`

how do i modify the code if i were to run as a package, ie: python2.7 -m org.somepackagename. udpbroadcast? i know i need to use the reactor, but how should i do it? i see that this example is using timeservice and UDPServer. i suspect i have to listen to `reactor.listenUDP(0, protocol)`??

i actually commented `application = Broadcaster().makeService()`, `change def __init__(self, controller, port):` to `def __init__(self, port):` and added the following code below

```
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
protocol = PingPongProtocol(port=8009)
lc = LoopingCall(protocol)
reactor.listenUDP(0, protocol)
reactor.run()
```

but it's still not sending and recv data

=========================================================

## EDITED CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
# See LICENSE for details.

"""
An example demonstrating how to send and receive UDP broadcast messages.

Every second, this application will send out a PING message with a unique ID.
It will respond to all PING messages with a PONG (including ones sent by
itself). You can tell how many copies of this script are running on the local
network by the number of "RECV PONG".

Run using twistd:

$ twistd -ny udpbroadcast.py
"""

from uuid import uuid4

from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.python import log



class PingPongProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    noisy = False

    # def __init__(self, controller, port):
    def __init__(self, port): # removed controller
        self.port = port


    def startProtocol(self):
        self.transport.setBroadcastAllowed(True)


    def sendPing(self):
        pingMsg = "PING {0}".format(uuid4().hex)
        self.transport.write(pingMsg, ('<broadcast>', self.port))
        log.msg("SEND " + pingMsg)


    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        print "RECV:" + datagram
        if datagram[:4] == "PING":
            uuid = datagram[5:]
            pongMsg = "PONG {0}".format(uuid)
            self.transport.write(pongMsg, ('<broadcast>', self.port))
            log.msg("RECV " + datagram)
        elif datagram[:4] == "PONG":
            log.msg("RECV " + datagram)



class Broadcaster(object):

    def ping(self, proto):
        proto.sendPing()


    def makeService(self):
        application = service.Application('Broadcaster')

        root = service.MultiService()
        root.setServiceParent(application)

        proto = PingPongProtocol(port=8009) #removed controller
        root.addService(internet.UDPServer(8009, proto))
        root.addService(internet.TimerService(1, self.ping, proto))

        return application


# application = Broadcaster().makeService() #commented. to use the code below

protocol = PingPongProtocol(port=8009)

from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
lc = LoopingCall(protocol)
# lc.start(3) #commented cos its throwing error

from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.listenUDP(8009, protocol)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: `twistd` is a Python program.  When you run `twistd` you are running Python.  What are you trying to ask?

Comment: basically i wanna run as package. e.g: python2.7 -m org.packagename. udpbroadcast

Comment: What's `SupervisorProtocol`?  You're instantiating that but it's not defined anywhere.  What happened to `PingPongProtocol` and `Broadcaster`?

Comment: sorry typo. its suppose to be PingPongProtocol.

Comment: Why do you expect it to send any data?  Are you running some other program as well?

Comment: maybe i am not clear about my problem. i ran the script on two machines and managed to send and receive data with no problem using the command: twistd -ny udpbroadcast.py. but i wanna run my script as a package instead, so i will be using the command: python2.7 -m org.somepackagename.udpbroadcast. how can i modify my code to allow running it as a package.

Comment: udpbroadcast.py binds to port 8555.  The rewritten version binds to port 0 - which causes the OS to randomly allocate a port.  If you run this twice, each version will use a different port and they won't talk to each other.

Comment: oh my god how did i miss that. i change it to 8555 and its working

Comment: i realise i can receive messages but not sending out. basically how do i call sendPing?

Comment: Can you post your modified code? I can't tell what code you're running right now.

Comment: hi nick, ok i added my edited code.it was able to receive msg last night but not send. but after some modification, i can't even get it to receive msg now.